# Rosinstall missing in python 2.7

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to install rosjava but that ends up failing because i'm missing rosinstall in python 2.7 -> dist-packages. Also missing vcstool. Was wondering if there was a way to get these back or fix up python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201156/rosinstall-missing-in-python-2.7/) by [hat13](https://answers.ros.org/users/21397/hat13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, you'd want to install the `rosinstall` and `vcstools` Python packages. I'd tell you exactly how to do that, but you've left out your OS name and version from your question. :p

---

In spite of the lack of information in the question (try and be more specific next time), here are a few common ways:

- On Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall python-vcstools`
- On OS X: `sudo pip install rosinstall vcstools`

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hat13](https://answers.ros.org/users/21397/hat13/) on 2015-01-16**:
Sorry about that. I'm using ubuntu and I tried that command and nothing shows in the python packages.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-16**:
You can try listing the files installed by those debian packages with something like `dpkg -L python-rosinstall`. Then you can double check that those files are there. If not you can uninstall and reinstall it.